# How do I write Sql server delete statement where a column value starts with the value of a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, delete-row, sql-delete

Here is what I have written below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[storedProcedureName]
@parameterName char 
AS
BEGIN
DELETE FROM Table
WHERE Table_ColumnNames like @parameterName%
END
```

Normally without a parameter I can write something like this (below) and this deletes every row that has name that starts with Adam in the ColumnName column. How do I achieve the same thing with a parameter which I have attempted above, I don't want it only to delete names that matches the parameterName but also names that starts with the value of parameterName.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[storedProcedureName]
AS
BEGIN
DELETE FROM Table
WHERE Table_ColumnNames like 'Adam%'
END
```

Comment: `@parameterName char` will truncate at `char(1)` meaning that if you pass "Adam" as a parameter value it will truncate to `A` and `LIKE 'A' + '%'` will end up deleting all rows beginning with `A`

Answer (score 3):

Try this one -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[storedProcedureName]

    @parameterName VARCHAR(30) 

AS BEGIN

    DELETE FROM dbo.[Table1]
    WHERE Table_ColumnNames LIKE @parameterName + '%'

END
```

Comment: I would be much more inclined to upvote this if you added a bit of explanatory text. e.g. Why you (correctly) changed the parameter datatype from `char` to `varchar`

Comment: @Martin Smith, your comment about `truncate the input parameter` matches with my point of view.